# Nested module 'not defined'

Tags: javascript, node.js, jasmine

In this utils.js module, I'm also calling another construct in constants.js which lives at the same level as utils.js. My issue occurs when the test fires, I get "Constants is not defined".

```
describe("A suite", function() {
   let Utils = require('../utils.js');
   it("contains spec with an expectation", function() {
       let utils = new Utils();
       expect(utils.testFunction()).toBe(true);
   });
});
```

Utils.js:

```
function Utils() {

const CONSTANTS = new Constants();
...
```

There is clearly something I'm not yet doing in order to make the Constants() object valid when the Jasmine test creates a new instance of Utils.

I've tried this thinking that Constants would then exist before Utils tried to instantiate it, but Jasmine doesn't seem to have access to it this way:

```
describe("A suite", function() {
   let Constants = require('../constants.js');
   let Utils = require('../utils.js');
   it("contains spec with an expectation", function() {
       let utils = new Utils();
       expect(utils.testFunction()).toBe(true);
   });
});
```

NOTE: If I remove the use of Constants.js from the picture, my test runs fine, evaluates correctly and passes.

Comment: it's hard to tell without seeing the full source files for both utils.js and constants.js.  Do you have a "require" in utils.cs to pull in constants.cs, like that "let Constants = require('../constants.js');" you have in the other file?  Well, since utils.js and constants.js are both in the parent directory, from utils.cs, it would be require('./constants.js').

Comment: I'll be a monkey's uncle. That was it! Thank you!

My issue was 2-fold.

1. I wasn't require()ing Constants.js inside Utils.js because we're just beginning to unit-test our Javascript. Everything is just loaded in a script tag in an HTML header.

2. Once I did use require(), I didn't have the path correct.